# .env variables causes errors with my object values that im getting from an axios get request in react

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, axios

So I have been using useState and axios to get requests to display values on my frontend that come from a MySQL database.This all works completely fine. However, when I try to use a `.env` variable with template literals inside my get request I get this error `"TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'profile_pic')"` (profile_pic) is from the database. I have included code all the way down to the object value 'profile_pic'

```
export default function Projectbody() {
    // const teacherId = 7
    const dotenv = require('dotenv').config();
    const teacherId = process.env.REACT_APP_LEVELUPWORKS_TEACHER_ID;
    const [results, setResults] = useState([])
    useEffect(() => {
     axios.get(`http://localhost:4000/getTeacherPhoto/${teacherId}`)
  .then(res => {setResults(res.data[0])})
            },[])

  const [active, setActive] = useState('menuCollapse') //menuCollapse is default, revert after editing
  const [item, setItem] = useState('itemObjective')

    return(
        <>
         {active === 'menuCollapse' && 
        <div className = "body-container"> 
            <div className = "body-menu" id = "Menu">
                <div className = "menu-item profile-pic"><img src = {results.profile_pic} className = "pic"></img></div>
```

I have imported useState and UseEffect as well as axios at the top of the page but again, everything works fine prior to using .env

here is my `.env` file which is located in the same folder as `public/src/package.json/node_modules` etc (which I think is the root?) its called `.env` as well btw.

```
REACT_APP_LEVELUPWORKS_TEACHER_ID = 1
```

I'm still new to react so I appreciate any/all help.

Comment: Is this create-react-app?

Comment: @Kid yeah it is.

Comment: If so, you don't need to use dotenv. Also, did you try to console `teacherId` ?

Comment: @Kid yeah i didnt think so with the dotenv lmao. and yep its undeclared.

Comment: remove dotenv, try console, restart server and lmk

Comment: @Kid works now. Ly <3

Answer (score 0):

Try importing dotenv outside your function. Maybe it's a component mount issue.